# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter

Tags: flutter, gradle, getter, audio-player, nameerror

Error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'AVAudioSessionCategory'.

- 'AVAudioSessionCategory' is from 'package:audioplayers_platform_interface/api/audio_context_config.dart'
  ('/D:/flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
  'category': category.name,
  ^^^^
  /D:/flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart:243:39:
  Error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'AVAudioSessionOptions'.
- 'AVAudioSessionOptions' is from 'package:audioplayers_platform_interface/api/audio_context_config.dart'
  ('/D:/flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_platform_interface-1.0.0/lib/api/audio_context_config.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
  'options': options.map((e) => e.name).toList(),

Answer (score 0):

Could be 2 possible issues causing it to not find the getter name..  but here are some possible troubleshoot solutions

1. You changed or wrongly spelt the packagename or name of your project in pubsec.yaml.. And forgot to change the individual files to that new name. (So do that correction)
2. You wrote the code for an older version of flutter, and later upgraded flutter causing a mismatch,
   If that's what you did, you need to downgrade your flutter SDK..  If you are in a hurry to meet a deadline, That will be a faster solution in this case, than updating the code line by line if its huge